# No module named 'base' even though base.py exists

Tags: python

Suppose a certain directory [checkerbot](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ST9sGqdiwAPin3OjQpjuuf75XU1IF3ed?usp=sharing) (You can download the files). From my current directory, I have this directory called `checkerbot` which contains 4 files, i.e. `base.py`, `checkers.py`, `__init__.py` and `model.py`.

```
In [1]: import checkerbot.checkers as ck                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d7411e2bfdb5> in <module>
----> 1 import checkerbot.checkers as ck

~/../main/checkerbot/checkers.py in <module>
----> 1 import base
      2 
      3 class Game:
      4         # Initializes the class.
      5         def __init__(self):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'
```

This error told me I have no `base.py` in the`checkerbot` directory, but it is false. How can I fix that? For your information, I am using python 3.7.6.

**UPDATE**

```
In [2]: import .base                                                            
  File "<ipython-input-2-e4256d58e84b>", line 1
    import .base
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Suppose my current directory is `main` and `checkerbot` is in `main/`. If I run `ipython` and then `from . import base` then I got :

```
In [1]: from . import base                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a8bda1f23f19> in <module>
----> 1 from . import base

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Another error :

```
In [5]: from checkerbot import base                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-3203dc774184> in <module>
----> 1 from checkerbot import base

~/../main/checkerbot/base.py in <module>
      1 import tensorflow as tf
      2 import numpy as np
----> 3 from model import model
      4 
      5 agent = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'
```

Comment: Try `import .base`?

Comment: you need to add the `.` in python3+

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I will update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
from . import base
```

That will provide a relative import of the `base` module in the `checkerbot` package.

A similar thing holds for the `model` module:

```
from .model import model
```

Comment: Look at the question

Comment: Your attempt doesn't answer my question

Comment: I don't know where I messed up, but in my head, it is all the same question.

Comment: It is not in checkerbot/. It is in the main/. The main/ contains checkerbot/. Why did you think I did `import checkerbot.checkers as ck`?

Comment: Are you up to modify your answer?

Comment: Yeah, I have just done it. It works now. I wasn't sure what you meant by from . import base. I didn't know it was in the file. I thought you meant in the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead

```
from . import base
```

**Edit**

Consider the following example:

```
└── foo
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── module_bar.py
    └── module_foo.py

$ cat foo/module_bar.py 
from . import module_foo

print(module_foo.load())

$ cat foo/module_foo.py 
def load():
    print("module foo is loaded")

$ python
Python 3.8.2 (default, May  4 2020, 20:05:11) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import foo.module_bar
module foo is loaded
```

This means, whenever you're importing a module from directory, your imports within the directory should start with `.`

Comment: You can download my module. Try it out with it. It doesn't seem to work for me

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the script from the checkbot directory? If are running the script from the parent directory just try out `from . import base` or `from checkerbot import base`.

Currently python probably searchs for `base.py` in your parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

justwrite the name of the folder contain in it

ex:

> > from pymouse.base import PyMouseMeta, PyMouseEventMeta